# Como popular DropDownListFor com informações de uma chave estrangeira?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho estas duas classes e preciso popular um *DropDownListFor* com as informações da classes `ModeloVeiculo`, sendo que esse DropDownListFor sera feito na 
create.cshtml da classe `Veiculo`, acredito que a pergunta correta seria, como carregar informações em uma DropDownListFor, sendo que essas informações são de uma chave estrangeira!

```cs
public class Veiculo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }            
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public ModeloVeiculo ModeloVeiculo { get; set; }
}

public class ModeloVeiculo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```cs
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModeloVeiculo, 
        new SelectList(Model.ModeloVeiculo, "ID", "Descricao"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModeloVeiculo)
</div>
```

Comment: @Tiago Silva falei bobeira mesmo preciso de um DropDownListFor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um amigo meu me ajudo o problema foi resolvido dessa maneira:

```cs
[Display(Name = "Modelo do veículo")]
public int? ModeloVeiculoID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ModeloVeiculoID")]
public virtual ModeloVeiculo ModeloVeiculo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

O estranho é que sua classe `Veiculo`, se refere a apenas um `ModeloVeiculo`, e ao utilizar um `CheckBox`, você estaria permitindo que o usuário selecionasse mais de uma opção. O que acho meio incoerente.

Mas apresentando uma solução:

Você vai ter que listar todos os `ModeloVeiculo`, passar por `ViewData/ViewBag` e adiciona-los através de um `foreach`:

```
[Controller]
ViewData["ModeloVeiculos"] = contexto.ModeloVeiculos.toList();
```

Então na `View`:

```
@{
    var modeloVeiculos = ViewData["ModeloVeiculos"] as IEnumerable<ModeloVeiculo>;
}

@foreach (var modeloVeiculo in modeloVeiculos )
{
    <div>
      <label>
       @Html.CheckBox("chk", false, new { @value = modeloVeiculo.ID })
       @modeloVeiculo.Nome
      </label>
    </div>
}
```

Então para receber e tratar esses dados no `Controller`.

```
string[] modelos = collection["chk"].Split(',');
var modeloVeiculos = new List<ModeloVeiculo>();
int parser;
foreach (string modelo in modelos)
{
      if (!modelo.Contains("false"))
      {
         if (int.TryParse(modelo, out parser))
             modeloVeiculos.Add(contexto.ModeloVeiculo.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == parser));
      }
}
```

Comment: Ola @Diego Zanardo obrigado pela ajuda, mas acho que me expressei errado não deu certo o código seu ( ou eu não consegui implementar corretamente), o que acontece e que escrevi checkbox porem o que preciso é de DropDownListFor, na classe MOdeloVeiculo sera add varios modelos e esses que forem add na hora do preenchimento da classe Veiculo quando chegar no campo ModeloVeiculo, preciso de um DropDownListFor que me traga as opções dos modelos que foram preenchidos na classe Veiculo!! Obrigado pela ajuda mais uma vez!!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi corretamente, mas vou responder conforme consegui entender.

Você pode criar uma classe para ser o seu ***Model*** que irá conter as propriedades do Veículo e uma lista para o usuário selecionar o Modelo do Veículo como essa:

```
public class VeiculoViewModel
{
    public VeiculoViewModel()
    {
        //Inicializa a lista de Modelos de Veiculo
        ModelosDeVeiculo = new List<SelectListItem>();     
    }

    public VeiculoViewModel(List<ModeloVeiculo> modelosDeVeiculo):this()
    {
        PreencherListaDeModelosDeVeiculo(modelosDeVeiculo);
    }

    //Dados do Veiculo
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    //Lista de Modelos do Veiculo
    public int IdModeloSelecionado { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ModelosDeVeiculo { get; set; }

    //Preenche a lista de Modelos do Veiculo
    private void PreencherListaDeModelosDeVeiculo(List<ModeloVeiculo> modelosDeVeiculo)
    {
        foreach(var modelo in modelosDeVeiculo)
        {
            ModelosDeVeiculo.Add(
                new SelectListItem() { 
                    Text = modelo.Descricao, 
                    Value = modelo.ID
                    }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

No ***Controller*** você pode obter uma lista dos seus Modelos de Veiculo e passá-la para o seu Model, que por fim irá preencher a lista.

```
public class ControllerVeiculo
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //Recupera uma lista de Modelos do Veiculo
        var listaDeModelosDeVeiculo = _repositorioModeloVeiculo.ObterTodos();
        return View(new VeiculoViewModel(listaDeModelosDeVeiculo));
    }
}
```

Já na sua ***View*** você poderia renderizar o *DropDownListFor* assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdModeloSelecionado, Model.ModelosDeVeiculo)
```