# Desabilitar DropDownList na View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

## Classe

```
public class ConfiguracaoEstado
{
  ....

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione ao menos um estado.")]
  [Display(Name = "Estado")]
  public int EstadoID { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

## Controller

```
private void createViewBag(ConfiguracaoEstado configuracaoestado)
{
  ViewBag.EstadoID = new SelectList(db.Estado, "Id", "uf", configuracaoestado.EstadoID);
  ....
}
```

## View

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstadoID, "Estado", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownList("EstadoID", String.Empty);
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoID)
  </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria que ao executar `ActionResult Edit(int? id)` o `DropDownList` fosse desabilitado.

Tentei assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EstadoID", String.Empty, new { disabled =  Model != null});
```

e não funcionou.

Então tentei assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstadoID,
                       (SelectList)ViewBag.EstadoID,
                       String.Empty, new {disabled = Model != null}
                     )
```

Ai acontece o seguinte:

1. Desabilita o controle, mas não exibe o conteúdo do `DropDownList`.
2. Se retiro o `String.Empty`, exibe o conteúdo, mas não o que esta gravado e sim o primeiro da tabela.

Com trazer o conteúdo correto do `DropDownList` e desabilitá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No topo da sua View, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
@{
    ddlProps = new { } as object;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        ddlProps = new { @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled"};
    }
}
```

Então fazer o seguinte no Helper sobrescreve o método.

```
@Html.DropDownList("EstadoID", String.Empty)
```

Assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EstadoID", null,String.Empty,ddlProps);
```

Apenas um dica na implementação da sua Controller:
Utilize um Bind para remover EstadoID na Action da sua controle, apenas por segurança.

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Exclude = "EstadoID")]MyObject model)
```

Comment: Na declaração do _ddlProps_ esta retornando o seguinte erro: *Cannot convert source type '{redeonly:string, disabled:string}' to target type 'anonymous type'*

Comment: Tente declarar o ddlProps como object, pois este erro é por está tentando converter um tipo anonimo ou outro.

Comment: Bom agora o erro esta na referência ao  `ddlProps` na criação do `DropDownList` com pode ser visot no imagem: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6B6FE80FB785B22C!89450&authkey=!AP9IEIwC_MnnTlY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Consegui resolvi o problema e já editei a resposta com o código correto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar JQuery.

Na *View* que renderiza a página de edição, você exibe normamente seu *dropdownlist*, porém adiciona o seguinte código JQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#EstadoID").prop("disabled", true);   
   });

   ... 

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstadoID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EstadoID)

   ...
```

Ou

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#EstadoID").attr('disabled','disabled');  
    });

   ... 

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstadoID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EstadoID)

   ...
```

Se você tiver interesse, no link abaixo tem uma outra forma de como renderizar um dropdownlist

[Como popular DropDownListFor com informações de uma chave estrangeira?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30763/como-popular-dropdownlistfor-com-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-uma-chave-estrangeira/31072#31072)

Comment: Apesar de utilizar a solução anterior, gostei de saber que podemos abordar a questão de outra forma. Valeu!